# How OAuth could be used in RESTfull AJAX-based Cliend-Server mobile app

Tags: ajax, facebook, authentication, mobile, oauth

Here's my current experimental app setup:
1. **Client** - a Phonegap application. Let's call it "native" because no html/js are requested from web server. Only AJAX JSONP rpc requests.
2. **Resource Server** - Drupal 7 with custom content types, Services module for delivery. **Basic Authentication** is used for authenticating AJAX requests.

There are no problems using "classic" registration/authentication where user enters login and password, which is then used in AJAX requests to access content.

But now I would like to implement OAuth as alternative to cumbersome yet-another manual registration, with extra features.

After some research I've came up to partial idea on how it should work so far:

- User launches **Client** app.
- **Client** opens WebView with URL to **Auth. Server** (let's say Facebook) login dialog, with parameter *redirect-uri* set to **Resource Server**.
- User enters FB login/password. User confirms access to name, email, etc. Success.
- **Auth. Server** redirects to **Resource Server** as defined in *redirect-uri* with generated *code* as parameter.
- **Resource server** sends server-side request providing generated *code*, *client-id*, *secret* to **Auth. Server's** API.
- **Auth. Server** returns *access-token*, *expiration*.
- *As I imagine*: **Resource Server** creates new account using information (email, name, date of birth, etc.) received from **Auth. Server**, if  account not already created, OR validates that this is already registered user that should be allowed to log in (using email, received from **Auth. Server**, database lookup, right?).
- and... now what?

I believe that **Resource Server** now can redirect WebView to some kind dummy address with special URI parameters in order to notify **Client** that authentication was successful, and AJAX calls now should be allowed.

But how that **Client** - **Resource Server** authentication should look like exactly? **Client** does not have login/password pair as in "classic" mode... Should *access token* be used as some kind changing (after every refresh... right?) password?

**EDIT**: In shorter form: Basic/Digest authentication is useless here, so with what technique could I authenticate mobile app AJAX requests to my web server using third-party OAuth authentication process.

Comment: Once you have an access token all the calls you make to the server will be using the accessToken.  You dont need there password.  Remember to save the refreshtoken becouse the access token will expire and you will need to use that to get a new one.

Comment: @DaImTo I believe you are talking about Auth. Sever, such as Facebook? Yes, I should use access token with it, but my question is about how **my** web (here **Resource Server**) server should allow entry for **Client** (mobile app) afetr OAuth authentication process. Basic/Digest authentication for AJAX calls here are useless without logins/passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You need your own Authentication Server so that you can generate your own access tokens that work with your Resource Server. Your access tokens will identify the calling application and user. Users who login to your authentication server will login via the Facebook OAuth flow instead of email/password.